# Integrating Knowledge into an existing website

Tags: knowledge, developer

I'm looking into leveraging our existing presence on Salesforce to create a help resource for our customers. My problem is that I am completely unfamiliar with Salesforce and need to somehow integrate article/help into a website that has no Salesforce related content on it, with as little of a footprint as possible. How would I do this?

I've done a little browsing and saw that it looks like you can allow public access to articles via an API, would this be the ideal way to go about things? Can I do all the basic things I would need over the API? Is there something more plug and play I can utilize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can have the access through API, a better way to set this up will be utilizing Salesforce’s capabilities around connecting with customers using communities. It can be achieved with most of point and click approach without the need of any extensive customization around API integration.

The use case you have can be addressed as:

1. Create a Knowledge Repository in Salesforce
2. Expose this as a Public Knowledge Base using Communities

A good starting point on setting up knowledge in Salesforce is the official [Knowledge resource guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_implementation_guide.pdf). To be able to access Knowledge articles from your external website, you can use [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_knowledge_support.htm), however there will be effort required at the caller's end to make sure they consume the response and render the retrieved information per their needs.

Taking the Community route, once you are done setting up the Knowledge, you can then turn towards creating a Community which your customers can utilize to access the knowledge articles. You can have a link on your external website to this knowledge base community.

Resources on Community can be found:

- [Setup and Manage Communities](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities.pdf)
- [Enable Public Access to Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_public_access.htm&type=5)
- [Enable Salesforce Knowledge in your Community](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/rss_setup_enabling_knowledge.htm)

Comment: Hi @jayant-das, thanks for the response! I've gone ahead and created a Knowledge base and even made it public and it works pretty well. My question now is how I display this content within my website that doesn't use Visualforce or any of that stuff. Are there any examples of using the Salesforce API within an external Javascript website?

Comment: You can access Knowledge articles using REST API, I have added reference to it in my answer. Hope this helps.