# How to share Knowledge Articles with external clients

Tags: knowledge

I'm looking for suggestions on how to share Knowledge Articles with external clients.

I have searched web and one way seems to be to setup a Community and then share articles by check marking which channel the article is shared (Internal, Partner, Customer, public knowledge).

Looking for detailed steps on how this, or other options, are done; so any info would be much appreciated.

other info - we are currently running Salesforce classic but we plan to move to Lightning soon - so not sure how that might affect my approach

Comment: You can find resources on [**this anwer**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/215463/) as how you can proceed building a KB and exposing those through Community. The guides are comprehensive and should provide you with a good starting point towards building this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this through Community Sharing Sets. See the trailhead here to work through an example of this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/community_rollout_impl/community_rollout_impl_sharing

You will need to enable the Knowledge object and configure it to match permission requirements for these clients.

Comment: Sharing Sets are used to share records within the Community Users. You cannot share a Knowledge Article using Sharing Sets.